# ASP.NET MVC Core2 Cookie Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

ENVIRONMENT (DEVELOPMENT):

Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core2 Web Application
https://localhost:44300/

ISSUE:

From a View Form, when I call the HttpPost method in the controller that has the [Authorize] attribute it fails and returns "This page isn't working...HTTP ERROR 400"

If I remove the SignInAsync and allow anonymous on the HttpPost, it works fine.

CODE IN STARTUP:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            //services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)    
            services.AddAuthentication("CookieSecurityScheme")
                .AddCookie("CookieSecurityScheme", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0);
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/");
                });

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
            app.UseRewriter(options);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "signin",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{agencyID}/{contactID}");
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
```

CODE IN CONTROLLER:

```
            // create claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, c_signed_in.FirstName + gFunc.SPACE + c_signed_in.FamilyName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, c_signed_in.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, c_signed_in.AccountPassword)
            //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, c_signed_in.Email)
        };

        // create principal
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

        // sign-in
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: "CookieSecurityScheme", principal: principal);
```

TRIED:

SignInAsync and SignOutAsync work fine and I can see that the user is authenticated via: HttpContext.User

I've looked through many examples on doing this and I can't see why this fails.

Comment: Since you are using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` there should be detailed error explanation on the page. Could you provide it to us please?

Comment: @hmnzr Yes, I would expect that, but I don't get anything - its just a big gray page that says "This page isn't working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 400". Also, if I put a break on the first line of code in the controller method, it never gets there.

Comment: over a week and no response! anybody??? otherwise is there another forum where I might be able to get some help?